# Is there any way to take a specific group of lines using File.ReadLines?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to grab every line after the first 2 lines in a text file and place them into a string.

what i have so far is

```
Count = File.ReadLines(filepath).Count();
String Lines = File.ReadLines(filepath.Skip(2).Take(Count -2).First());
```

This grabs the first line that I want but fails to collect any lines after that point.
I'm assuming that this is because a string can only hold a single line ? I'm not really sure if that's what im doing wrong or not but if it is I can't find a way to remedy the problem.

Comment: Use an array:  `string[] lines = File.ReadLines(filepath).Skip(2).Take(Count - 2)));, and drop the `.First()`.  You can probably drop the `Take()` as well: `string[] lines = File.ReadLines(filepath).Skip(2);`

Comment: This gives me a "cannot implicitly convert type <string> to string[] error

Comment: `ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, so either change the `lines` variable to `IEnumerable<string> lines` or call `.ToArray()` at the end:  `string[] lines = File.ReadLines(filepath).Skip(2).ToArray();`

Comment: Works fantastically ! thank you. If you form it as an answer ill give you your answered question points !

Comment: You're welcome.  Answer posted - happy coding :)

Comment: Don't forget if you want it as just a _single_ string to use `string.Join`, ex: `string OneLine = string.Join(string.Empty, File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Skip(2));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, not a `string`.  The call to `.Take()` is unnecessary as you want everything after the first two lines, and the call to `First()` will take the first result in the sequence and discard the rest (which is not what you want).

So declare `lines` as `IEnumerable<string>` and remove `Take()` and `First()` (also pay attention to the order of your parantheses, as your posted code should have had a `)` after `filepath`):

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(filepath).Skip(2);
```

Alternatively, you could define `lines` as an array of string or a `List<T>` and call `ToArray()` or `ToList()` at the end of your LINQ statement, like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadLines(filepath).Skip(2).ToArray();
```

or

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(filepath).Skip(2).ToList();
```

You could also use `var`:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filepath).Skip(2);
```

Comment: there's also just `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Skip(2)`

Comment: Yep - lots of ways to do this :)